# Error on check-env.sh installing Apache Kylin on Hortonworks

Tags: shell, hadoop, environment, hortonworks-sandbox, kylin

I'm trying to install Apache Kylin on a Hortonworks Sandbox following the instructions provided on [Apache Kylin install](http://kylin.apache.org/docs/install/index.html).

I set up on my .bashrc export KYLIN_HOME='/root/kylin' (inside this folder there are the Kylin Binaries ).

In step 3 it say to run bin/check-env.sh to check for a enviroment issue, this  script is under kylin/build instead of inside kylin/ so, i tryied to set KYLIN_HOME to '/root/kylin/build' and '/root/kylin'

I receive this error with '/root/kylin'

> $ bin/check-env.sh: line 23: /root/kylin/bin/find-hadoop-conf-dir.sh: No such file or directory
>   KYLIN_HOME is set to /root/kylin
>   bash: /root/kylin/bin/get-properties.sh: No such file or directory
>   Please set kylin.env.hdfs-working-dir in kylin.properties

And this error with '/root/kylin/build'

> Retrieving hadoop conf dir...
>   ls: cannot access /root/kylin/build/tool/kylin-tool-*.jar: No such file or directory
>   KYLIN_HOME is set to /root/kylin/build
>   ls: cannot access /root/kylin/build/tool/kylin-tool-*.jar: No such file or directory
>   Please set kylin.env.hdfs-working-dir in kylin.properties

How can i fix this to run successfully Kylin inside Hortonworks Sandbox? What am I missing around?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue with Kylin 2.2 on HDP 2.6 (running on ubuntu 16.04) and it turned out to be a simple java setting issue : the JAVA_HOME and PATH variable were not properly set.

For  some  reasons, the check-env.sh  script does not properly handle this exception and you get these misleading unrelated error messages. Once set, Kylin could be started without any problem.

Hope  this help  !